# how to run cpufreqd in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: cpufreq

I've just installed cpufreqd in a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 through:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufreqd
```

After that, I tried to execute it by `sudo cpufreqd`. But nothing happens (neither error or indicator displayed). Even I can't see any new process in the system monitor.
Then I installed cpufrequtils through `sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils` and I tried again to execute `sudo cpufreqd` with the same (no) result.

I know there exist indicator-cpufreq, I was using it for some time; but I realized that I need something more configurable and complete like cpufreqd.

Similar alternatives to this are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`indicator-cpufreq` is what you need for the panel

The daemon is the core part and plugins (I only know the panel one though ;)) let you have control over what, when, how. The indicator is one of those plugins (and the easiest one).

---

cpufreqd is started automatically after installing. For it to work you need either APM, a recent ACPI or PMU. **And the modules cpufreq_powersave, cpufreq_userspace, and cpufreq_ondemand (you need to load these for cpufreq to work)**. It has a [configuration file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/cpufreqd.conf.5.html) that explains all the different settings in `/etc/` and has samples. What is best for you is up to you to decide ;)

---

An alternative would be TLP.

Just a warning: the tools for management should already be in the kernel (and working). It is called "laptop-mode-tools".

Comment: Now, I messed up something and doesn't matter which governor or frequency I select, the cpus are always in 2.90GHz (the maximum). Is there any way to reset the cpufreqd.conf and any other configuration file for this to the default values??

Comment: 99% chance that means the modules are not loaded. check with "lsmod" if they are.

Comment: Hello @Rinzwind, thank you for your help.
Here output for lsmod: http://pastebin.com/DSTSd2NG
Here output for cpufreq-info: http://pastebin.com/QszeTYMj